# Stars & Bars Question: Identical Balls in Distinct Boxes

Tags: combinatorics

I am terrible at combinatorics so any and all help would be appreciated.

20 identical balls are put into 10 distinct boxes so that at most 3 boxes are empty. In how many ways can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Starting a question with "I am terrible at xxx..." is just shorthand for "I haven't tried to solve this problem". How many ways are there of placing 20 balls into 10 boxes with no boxes empty? If one is empty, this is placing 20 balls into 9 boxes with no boxes empty. Etc.

Comment: Sorry to shatter your illusion and knock you off your high horse but it just so happens that there are people who are so unfamiliar with a topic that they cannot solve a problem without another person's aid despite how long they attempt the problem. But thanks for your incredibly useful underhanded condescension.

Comment: Anyway, I wanted to solve this problem by breaking it up into several cases: 0 boxes empty, 1 empty, 2 empty, and 3 empty. In the case with 0 boxes empty, would it be 19 choose 9?

Comment: Yes, that's the right approach. You have to remember to take into account how many ways there are of selecting nine boxes of 10, and so forth.

Comment: If there are zero boxes empty, then you must put one ball in each box, and then distribute the remaining ten freely among all ten boxes.

Comment: @user155812:  For $0$ boxes empty, yes, your $\binom{19}{9}$ is correct. For $1$ box empty, the empty box can be chosen in $\binom{10}{1}$ ways. For each of these ways, the balls can be put in the $9$ boxes that are supposed to be non-empty in $\binom{19}{8}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{10}{1}\binom{19}{8}$. Do something similar for $2$ empty, $3$ empty and add up the $4$ cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can split this into $4$ cases based on the number of empty boxes, and use [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) for each case.

---

**Case 1**: No empty boxes.

We place $1$ ball in each box, and we imagine $9$ dividers and the remaining $10$ balls, so the number of possible ways to arrange the $19$ objects is $$\binom{19}{9}$$

**Case 2**: One empty box.

There are $10$ ways to choose the empty box. We place $1$ ball in each of $9$ boxes, and imagine $8$ dividers with the remaining $11$ balls, so the number of ways to arrange the $19$ objects is $$10\binom{19}{8}$$

**Case 3**: Two empty boxes.

There are $\binom{10}{2}=45$ ways to choose which boxes are empty. We place $1$ ball in each of $8$ boxes, and imagine $7$ dividers with the remaining $12$ balls, which gives $$45\binom{19}{7}$$

**Case 4**: Three empty boxes.

There are $\binom{10}{3}=120$ ways to choose which boxes are empty. We place $1$ ball in each of $7$ boxes, and imagine $6$ dividers with the remaining $13$ balls, which gives $$120\binom{19}{6}$$

---

Our final answer is

$$120\binom{19}{6}+45\binom{19}{7}+10\binom{19}{8}+\binom{19}{9}=\boxed{6371498}$$

Comment: For each case where there IS an empty box, shouldn't you multiply by $\dbinom{10}{n}$, where $n$ is the number of boxes you want to be empty? So for example, if there is one box empty, there would be $\dbinom{10}{1}$$\dbinom{19}{8}$ because there the boxes are distinct, so it matters which ones are selected to be empty.

Comment: @user155812 You're right, I've fixed it :)

Comment: @user155812 in fact, it may help to understand the generalization to correct it to "for each case you multiply by $\binom{10}{n}$ where $n$ is the number of boxes you want to be empty" since we could have multiplied by $\binom{10}{0}=1$ in the case of zero empty boxes.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your response Zubin. This is the answer I had gotten initially, but my lack of confidence combined with the fact that my classmates had gotten another answer made me unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Can you do the case where no boxes are empty?  That is a standard stars and bars.  Then pick $9,8,7$ of the boxes (how many ways each?) and do the case where no boxes are empty.  Add them up.

Comment: In the case with no empty boxes, would it be 19 choose 9? If it is, then I think I'm on the right track.

Comment: Furthermore, would the case with 1 box empty be $\dbinom{10}{1}$$\dbinom{19}{8}$?

Comment: Yes $19 \choose 9$ is the case where you do not allow any empty boxes.  Your second is correct as well-$10 \choose 1$ picks the empty box and $19\choose 8$ puts the balls in the rest with no empties.